# serving feather icons from s3 in Django & BootStrap

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-bootstrap4

I'm having troubles serving feathers icon & other fonts from AWS S3. It would return Access Denied (403 Forbidden).

example file: Feather-Iconse198.ttf

Other contents like images, JS and CSS serves well. Here is the bucket CORS configuration I have.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The resource path is correct. The object URL when clicked from the AWS S3 console also return the same exact error - access denied.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the bucket policy?

Comment: @jellycsc, The bucket policy is empty. I intentionally left it so. Need I write any policy?

Comment: You want to make everything in your bucket public?

Comment: @jellycsc, not sure what to do. What do you recommend?